# AutoCompleteTextView in a AlertDialog Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, autocompletetextview

I have tried to work this out but nothing pops into my head, the following code is a part of an application that has movies and if i click a search button it creates a dialog builder with a AutoCompleteTextView for typing a name of a movie.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(ThisScreen.search_context, android.R.style.Theme_Black));          
            ///// autocomplete thingie
            String[] name_mov = new String[movie_categ.size()];
            name_mov = movie_categ.toArray(name_mov);           

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name_mov);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View search_View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.this_movie_search, null);            

            myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                    search_View.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);      

            myAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
            myAutoComplete.setThreshold(2);

            /////               
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(searchView);
            alertDialogBuilder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    isFirstDialog = 0;                  
                }
            });
            alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();  

            if (movie_categ.isEmpty() ) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(ThisScreen.search_context, "Verify net conn.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                isFirstDialog = 0;
            }
            else alertDialog.show();
```

and this_movie_search.xml has

```
  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/movie_name"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_search"
      android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
      android:hint="@string/search_hint"
      android:ems="10"
      android:maxLength="50"
      />
```

The list with the suggestions doesnt appear, any ideas why?

Comment: Just to clarify, your movie_categ contains your movie names? Did you verify whether it's being filled properly? I don't see a declaration for it anywhere or where it is filled. If you manually create an array of test data in code, does it display?

Comment: Yes, the movie_categ contain the movie names. And i have verified it and it is being filled properly. I've seen the values through debugging. ( movie_categ is an ArrayList<String> ) @user3427079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for the answer for too long and didn't saw the obvious, i should have declared my  myAutoComplete from the beginning as 'AutoCompleteTextView' type, and it works.

```
   final AutoCompleteTextView myAutoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.AutoCompleteTextView_declared_in_the_xml);
   // autocomplete thingie

        String[] name_mov = new String[movie_categ.size()];
        name_mov = movie_categ.toArray(name_mov);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name_mov);   

        myAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
        myAutoComplete.setThreshold(2);

        //
```